# How to set validation set (in my timeseries forecasting problem)

Tags: python, validation, machine-learning, time-series

this is a rather specific question to my problem. I would really appreciate it if you could guide me in the right direction here :)

I have n timeseries, each containing 300 datapoints (5 minutes in sec). I'm planning to use the Python Darts library for a start since it allows one to pass all n timeseries within a list to the model.

i.e.

```
model.fit(series = [s1, s2, ..., sn])
```

Eventually the model should take the first 4 minutes and predict the next 1 minute.

How would you set the validation set?
Since each series is quite short by itself, I don't want to cut it even shorter to make a validation set out of it and especially the last minute is very important therefore the model needs to get trained on this too.

I'm aware of techniques like rolling window cross validation but I'm still wondering whether this is the right approach here.

I could increase the density of datapoints, i.e. making each series 600 datapoints long --> 2 points for each second. But the problem would remain the same, predicting the next minute based on the previous 4.

I've trained a toy model on just 30 series without a validation set, but something doesn't feel right about not having one.

Answer (score 0):

It is essential to have validation dataset as this will help you to assess the performance of the model. The short time series data is very common challenge that exist. However, there are some strategies which you can use to mitigate these challenges.

**Rolling window cross validation:** As you have mentioned, better to use rolling window cross validation. create a validation set by using a fixed window size of last-minute data and train the model on the rest of the data.

Then move the window in time forward and retrain the model to learn from the last-minute data as well.  This way the model can learn from even the last-minute data which is very important to make accurate predictions.

Other techniques to consider are the following:

(i) Leave-P-Out Cross-validation

(ii) Holdout validation

Also try ensemble methods.